# Mapping a document to a Java object that start with 'is'

Tags: java, firebase, mapping

I am trying to map an firebase document to a POJO with the using the toObject(myObject.class) as it appears on https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data (under 'Custom Object').

Everything works fine except for one thing:
I have a boolean in the DB that is named 'isCancelled', but when I map the document to an object I get the following message:

> ## WARN 20180 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] c.g.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper    : No setter/field for isCancelled found on class main.modals.ServiceRequest ##.

I have tried changing the variable name in my POJO to 'cancelled' and changing the setters to be 'setIsCancelled' (Automatic creation of setters produced a 'setCancelled' without the 'is').

** full SreviceRequest POJO:

```
package main.modals;

import java.util.Date;

public class ServiceRequest {
private boolean fallDetected;
private boolean isCancelled;
private Date requestStartTime;
private String requestType;
private String requestedByPatientID;
private String status;
private Date updatedAt;

public ServiceRequest() {
    super();
}

public boolean isFallDetected() {
    return fallDetected;
}

public boolean isCancelled() {
    return isCancelled;
}

public Date getRequestStartTime() {
    return requestStartTime;
}

public String getRequestType() {
    return requestType;
}

public String getRequestedByPatientID() {
    return requestedByPatientID;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public Date getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
}

public void setFallDetected(boolean fallDetected) {
    this.fallDetected = fallDetected;
}

public void setCancelled(boolean isCancelled) {
    this.isCancelled = isCancelled;
}

public void setRequestStartTime(Date requestStartTime) {
    this.requestStartTime = requestStartTime;
}

public void setRequestType(String requestType) {
    this.requestType = requestType;
}

public void setRequestedByPatientID(String requestedByPatientID) {
    this.requestedByPatientID = requestedByPatientID;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}
```

}

Comment: What does `ServiceRequest` look like?

Comment: @Andreas  I've added it to my question. Thanks for your response!

Comment: For non-boolean properties, method names must be `getXxx` and `setXxx`, e.g. for property `name` the methods would be `getName` and `setName`. For boolean values, methods must be `isXxx` and `setXxx`, e.g. for property `done` the methods would be `isDone` and `setDone`. --- The methods for property `isCancelled` would be `isIsCancelled` and `setIsCancelled`.

Comment: I thought that I tried it before but now I did it again and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Andreas It sounds like you found the solution. Can you post it as an answer so that Shen can accept it, and I can upvote? :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Shen already posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it thanks to Andreas comment:
For non-boolean properties, method names must be getXxx and setXxx, e.g. for property name the methods would be getName and setName. For boolean values, methods must be isXxx and setXxx, e.g. for property done the methods would be isDone and setDone. --- The methods for property isCancelled would be isIsCancelled and setIsCancelled.
Thank you!